# Copy a public image to Azure Storage with an api_key query string in the URI

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm using the C# Azure Storage client to fetch an image, then copy to an Azure Storage blob container, with the following format:

```
https://some-image-server.com/2023/03/13.png?api_key=my-api-key
```

I'm using `StartCopyFromUriAsync` like this:

```
await blobClient.StartCopyFromUriAsync(new Uri(imageUrl));
```

My code works well with regular public images without the `api_key` query string. But with the image format above, the client copies 0 KB to Azure Storage with a `Copy Status` of `Failed` (the response header states a generic 500 error). Is this a no-go, since the image isn't truly public? Do I have to settle with using streams or other alternatives?

Comment: What happens when you copy the image URL in a browser? Is the image displayed correctly? Also, please check if your image server supports “HEAD” request for the image URL?

Comment: It is displayed in the browser. The issue is that this is from a third-party partner so it isn't *my* server.

Comment: If I understand correctly when you use the URL with API key, you get a 0 byte blob and 500 error. Is that correct? If that's the case, can you try to make a HEAD request against that URL in Postman and share the result? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> The issue you are getting from the  `StartCopyFromUriAsync` method does not support copying images that require authentication.

The image requires an `api_key` query string to be accessed, which is not public.

To copy the image to Azure Storage, you need to download the image using an `HTTP client` that can authenticate the request with the `api_key` query string.

After downloading the image, you need upload it to Azure Storage using the `UploadAsync` method of the `BlobClient`

For more information, check the [Github Issue #32684](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/32684)

```
HttpClient http_Client = new HttpClient();
http_Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("api_key", apiKey);

HttpResponseMessage resp = await http_Client.GetAsync(imageUrl);
resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
Stream contentStream = await resp.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
BlobServiceClient blobService_Client = new BlobServiceClient(conn_String);
BlobContainerClient container_Client = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(container);
BlobClient blob_Client = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blob);

await blobClient.UploadAsync(contentStream, true);
```

Sample copying one storage to another storage.

Copying a public image to Azure Storage with an `api_key` query string in the URI using method `StartCopyFromUriAsync`

```
BlobServiceClient srcBlobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(srcConnectionString);
BlobServiceClient destBlobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(destConnectionString);

BlobContainerClient srcContainerClient = srcBlobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(srcContainerName);
BlobContainerClient destContainerClient = destBlobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(destContainerName);

BlobClient srcBlobClient = srcContainerClient.GetBlobClient(srcBlobName);
BlobClient destBlobClient = destContainerClient.GetBlobClient(destBlobName);

await destBlobClient.StartCopyFromUriAsync(srcBlobClient.Uri);
```

[image]

In Azure

[image]

For further information check this [Blog.](https://markheath.net/post/copying-blobs-with-v12-sdk)

Comment: This is not correct. The source blob should be publicly accessible somehow which is the case with OP.